# Why is a NTP query sent to many servers

Tags: linux, ntpd

I have ntpd installed on Ubuntu and it already had some public NTP servers in the config file. When I capture the NTP packets on Wireshark, the NTP query is sent to a bunch of IP addresses and I get a reply from those IP addresses. What is actually going on? Is it taking timestamps from all the NTP servers and then choosing the most accurate one?

Note: I actually don't know much about NTP, just noticed this behavior on Wireshark and was curious.

Comment: There is a standard for NTP -- `https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8633.html` -- which runs to 26 pages. It recommends at least four NTP servers are consulted to avoid rogue sources and find some concensus.

Comment: Duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/326872/117549 ?